# How can I create a number selector in WatchKit?

Tags: swift, user-interface, watchkit, watchos

I would like to create a number selector in the same style as the ones used in the stock workout app (with the selected value surrounded by - and +). See screenshot below:

[image]

Is there a built-in component for doing this or would I have to construct it myself using a label and two buttons? I've looked at the slider but I don't think that gives this option.

Comment: I guess you have to make it your own.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking. Just getting started so want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: I have found an example what you are looking for: https://makeapppie.com/2015/04/26/swift-watchkit-programming-sliders-on-the-apple-watch/

Comment: But it's not build in component as you can see :)

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know also.